# Hook=componentUpdated of Vue directive not triggered

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I just met one issue, if one component only update its own data, it will not trigger the hook=**componentUpdated** of the directive at the parent component.

As [Vue official Guide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Hook-Functions) said:

> componentUpdated: called after the containing component’s VNode and
> the VNodes of its children have updated.

It seems **componentUpdated** should be triggered.

Did I do something wrong? or misunderstand something?

At below demo, hit **Click Me!** button then you will see **componentUpdated** is not called.

But when click **change data** (execute similar behavior with **click me!**, the difference is it changes the data at parent component), it will trigger correctly.

Many thanks for any.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.component('child', {
  template: `<div>{{point}}
                <span style="background-color:gray;font-weight:bold;color:red">
                  -{{mytest}}
                </span>
                <button @click="plusOne()">Click me!</button>
             </div>`,
  props: ['point'],
  data(){
    return {
      mytest: 1
    }
  },
  updated: function () {
    console.log('updated component=child')
  },
  methods: {
    plusOne() {
      this.mytest += 1
    }
  }
})

let vMyDirective = {}
vMyDirective.install = function install (Vue) {

  Vue.directive('my-directive', {
    inserted: function () {
      console.log('!!!directive for inserted')
    },
    bind: function bind (el, binding, vnode) {
      console.log('!!!directive for bind')
    },
    componentUpdated: function componentUpdated (el, binding, vnode) {
      console.log('!!!directive for component updated')
    },
    update: function () {
      console.log('!!!directive for update')
    }
  })
}

Vue.use(vMyDirective)

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      testValues: ['label a', 'label b'],
      testIndex: 1
    }
  },
  methods:{
    pushArray: function() {
      this.testValues.push('label c')
    },
    changeData: function () {
      this.testIndex += 1
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button v-on:click="pushArray()">Add one Child!!!</button>
  <button v-on:click="changeData()">Change Data - {{testIndex}}</button>
  <div v-my-directive>
    <child v-for="(item, index) in testValues" :key="index" :point="item"></child>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great question. Apparently this is very worthy of being a [new Vue Issue](https://new-issue.vuejs.org/). It's probably that the documentation is misleading in this case. Just like in React, in Vue, data only flows 1 way, which is from parent to child. If this works, it would probably cause a lot of other problems.

Comment: @JacobGoh That may be true, If so, probably the guide should uses accurate description like `componentUpdated: called after the containing component’s VNode and the VNodes of its children have been remounted.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Vue Team Feedback](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/8288), it is not one issue on the hook=**componentUpdated**, it is my misunderstanding on the words.

For the prerequisite of the hook=**comopnentUpdated** is triggered, it is the VNode which the directive binds to already changed. That means if only child VNode changes, Vue will not catch it probably like what @Jacob Goh said in the comments (only flows one way).

So **componentUpdated** doesn't means it will detect child components are updated or not, it only means **when** will be triggered.